# Good clustering method for compact clusters

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning

Suppose I have a LARGE dataset with unknown labels (around 40000 points) where the pairwise Euclidean distance does not differ too much ( mostly 11- 13, some 6-9). Which clustering algorithm should I use for efficient clustering?

I did try hierarchical clustering with ward linkage and evaluate using some heuristic scoring method like Silhouette and it gives a very bad score (highest 0.1)

Comment: `Euclidean distance does not differ too much` How many dimensions (features) does your dataset have?

Comment: @ttnphns, 74 features.

Comment: Have you heard of the curse of dimensionality? Consider first doing PCA to reduce to up to, say, 10 dimensions.

Comment: @ttnphns, yes but I cannot do so because I need to retain the features without mixing them up in PCA. In general, I want to avoid feature extraction and use only feature selection.